# Find an orthogonal basis for ℝ3 that begins with an orthogonal basis for Col()

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

The problem is as follows:

Find an orthogonal basis for ℝ3 that begins with an orthogonal basis for Col(A). The matrix A is given in the image below (do not know how to display matrices correctly in text).

[My calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRvOf.jpg)

Is this a correct answer to the problem? Or do i need to use the Gram-Schmidt process directly on Col(A) before i find the reduced row echelon form of A?

Comment: Use \pmatrix{entry& entry \\ next row & \dots}  between $ signs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span of the two vectors you found is
$$
\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}
=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\0\end{bmatrix}:\ x,y\in\mathbb R\right\}.
$$
So your candidate for the basis cannot span neither the second nor the third column.

You have to do Gram-Schmidt, not forgetting that you will often (as in this case) get some zeros; since the dimension of col$(A)$ is $2$.

Comment: So if i apply the Gram-Schmidt process, i get two of the vectors for an orthogonal basis for ℝ3. What's the easiest way to find the third?

Comment: Would it be possible to calculate the cross product, and use this as the third vector?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way. In general, you could complete your list with the whole canonical basis and then do Gram-Schmidt.